# Why are modules available for PHP command line, not PHP-Apache?

Tags: php, apache, php-7.2, amazon-linux

I'm setting up an Amazon Linux environment, and after installing some modules:

`sudo yum install php-xml
sudo yum install php-gd`

for example... and installing Imagick, and restarting (`sudo service httpd restart`) it does not seem to be installing for PHP-Apache. I'm using the official PHP7.2 in Amazon Linux 2 and oddly enough, for example `xml_parser_create()` does work in the `php -a` console, but when I put it in a php file, it causes exception when going to the php file, blank screen. Oddly enough it's not even getting the function not defined error to the /var/log/httpd logs.

`phpinfo()` also does not show Imagick or gd although installed.

I have checked php ini files for `disabled_functions` and didn't find anything else that would otherwise be an obvious breakage in the default install... is there a new way I'm supposed to enable PHP modules for the *Apache* php install?

Comment: there is a php.ini for the command line and one for `PHP-Apache` make sure they are added to both

Comment: Pay close attention to the actual INI-file used by the CLI and Apache - it is in the middle of the very first table in `phpinfo()` output

Comment: @IVOGELOV I didn't see any disable_function directives in any ini files though. This is a new setup so it's surprising they have it set to not load new modules by default.

Comment: As I said - running `phpinfo()` once through the CLI and once through Apache and then checking whether they are using the same INI file - specifically the `Loaded Configuration File` row (7th from top to bottom)

Comment: The reason may be also in the `extension_dir` directive. I had the same problem on Windows and once I replaced `"ext"` with the full path, it resolved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others may have noted elsewhere there is another module I think it was `service php-fpm restart`? that is necessary on RHL

Comment: Easier than rebooting the server to find it magically found the modules :)